# How to check response to an invalid input with pytest and monkeypatch

Tags: pytest, monkeypatching

I am trying to test a component that handles inputs in python

I can test for a valid input, but the test for invalid input does not work. I am not getting any output trapped for the error message.

The component holds the user in a loop until a valid input is made. I have simulated this using a loop in the test and monkeypatch to simulate the input

```
import sys
import pytest


class Input():
    """ A class to validate inputs and process the response if valid."""
    def __init__(self, prompt, processes):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.processes = processes
        """
        processes is a dict of tuples keyed on valid inputs.
        The first element of the tuple is a function/process to be called
        The second is a list of args to send to the function.
        """

    def invoke(self):
        """Get the input and return the result if valid."""
        response = self._get_input()
        process = self.processes[response]
        result = process[0](*process[1])
        return result

    def _get_input(self):
        """Loop until a valid input is made."""
        while True:
            response = input(self.prompt)
            if response in self.processes:
                return response
            print("Invalid input")


def input_Y(value):
    assert value == 'Y input'

def test_invalid(monkeypatch, capsys):
    prompt = "Enter 'Y' to proceed, 'Q' to quit: "
    processes = {
        'Y': (input_Y, ['Y input']),
        'Q': (sys.exit, ['user quit']),
    }

    for response in ['P', 'Q']:
        monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda name: response)
        if response == 'P':
            captured = capsys.readouterr()
            assert captured.out.strip() == 'Invalid input'
        else:
            with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as excinfo:
                Input(prompt, processes).invoke()
            assert excinfo.value.code == 'user quit'
```

Here 'P' is an invalid entry (it does not appear in processes). The 'Q' (quit) process works as expected.

How can I check the error message